# How is it possible to intergrate a phpBB3 style but use an entirely different style sheet?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, phpbb3

I am trying to intergrate phpbb3 with my site, I have managed to do it but the problem is that some of the styles cross over and so the text of the phpbb looks completly wrong. Is there a way to keep the styles from phpbb3 and my site seperate while keeping them intergrated and not using iframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to break up the CSS file of your site to multiple files:

A) the ones with common settings for both site and forum,

B) another ones with settings that should be used only by the site, not the forum.

And then in the forum include just the A ones. Vice versa the forum uses some stylesheets that the site does not. That's how I use it on my website with integrated phpbb3 forum.

---

Another solution -more complicated and probably not so fine (and fun)- is to pinpoint the things that you don't like to be taken from your site to your forum and modify the forum's CSS.